# How do you delete an item in a ListView with a GridView in WPF

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview

I have a very simple list management operate where I have the following typed list:

```
private class BMark
        {
            public string folder { get; set; }
            public string shortName { get; set; }
        }
        private List<BMark> mBookmarks;
```

The list, mBookMarks, it used as the ItemSource in a ListView using a GridView. This is the markup:

```
            <ListView Margin="5" Name="lvBookmarks" 
              SelectionChanged="lvBookmarks_SelectionChanged" >
                <ListView.View >
                    <GridView x:Name="gridView"  >
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Folder Path" Width="350"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding folder}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Short Name" Width="170"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding shortName}" />
                    </GridView>
                    
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

The following is part of the code:

```
        private void btnApply_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mBookmarks[lvBookmarks.SelectedIndex].shortName = txtShortName.Text;
            lvBookmarks.Items.Refresh();
        }

        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mBookmarks.RemoveAt(lvBookmarks.SelectedIndex);

            lvBookmarks.Items.Refresh();
        }

        private void btnMoveDown_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (lvBookmarks.SelectedIndex >= lvBookmarks.Items.Count - 1) return;

            int x = lvBookmarks.SelectedIndex;
            mBookmarks.Reverse(x, 2);
            lvBookmarks.Items.Refresh();
            lvBookmarks.SelectedIndex = x + 1;
        }

        private void btnMoveUp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (lvBookmarks.SelectedIndex == 0) return;

            int x = lvBookmarks.SelectedIndex;
            mBookmarks.Reverse(x - 1, 2);
            lvBookmarks.Items.Refresh();
            lvBookmarks.SelectedIndex = x - 1;
        }
```

btnApply_Click simply appies changes to the shortName in the list. btnMoveDown and btnMoveUp move the selected item down or up.  All of these work fine with the code shown above.  However, btnDelete is driving me crazy.  The item is deleted from the mBookmarks list but calling lvBookmarks.Items.Refresh() results in the following exception:

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')'

If I don’t call lvBookmarks.Items.Refresh() the GridView is not updated and if I try to select an item beyond the new count I get the same exception shown above (as expected).

I've searched every source I'm aware of but haven't found anything resembling this.  There are lot's of examples of using ListView with a GridView but none of them seem to focus on updates. I've done all this in Windows Forms--it was very easy to do with owner draw lists.

Comment: In WPF, you don't need to update ListView manually. Replace the List with a ObservableCollection and bind it with a ListView. Then the change in the ObservableCollection will be automatically reflected to the ListView.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I did that this morning based on something I found related to a DataGrid.  Using an ObservableCollection, I basically get the same error on the delete.  So, I put a try/catch around the delete.  I tried it and caught the exception.  When I continued, everything was where I expected it to be.  The item was deleted without further issues.  Can you post a simple example--maybe I missed something.

Comment: The use of ObservableCollection is very basic of WPF and you can find many examples on this. If you provide a minimal reproducible example (e.g. GitHub repository), perhaps I can dig into the cause of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the `List<BMark>` with an `ObservableCollection<BMark>`, you don't have to bother to call to `Refresh()`:

```
private ObservableCollection<BMark> mBookmarks;

private void btnApply_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    mBookmarks[lvBookmarks.SelectedIndex].shortName = txtShortName.Text;
}

private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    mBookmarks.RemoveAt(lvBookmarks.SelectedIndex);
}
```